# How to send data via bluetooth charcateristics in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using flutter_blue_plus .
I have to send 0x30 and  0x97757d92(token String) through a charcateristics.. i tried sending like

`await s.characteristics[3].write([0x31]+ utf8.encode(tokenString)  );`

Do i have to follow any other steps in order to send tokenString